# How to add sql query to custom PHP page?

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have been creating a simple blog page for my Prestashop website. SO far I have been able to create the following files and the template is displaying correctly.

**BlogController.php** (located at /controllers/front directory)

```
<?php

class BlogControllerCore extends FrontController
 {
  public $php_self = 'blog.php';

  public function setMedia() 
  {
          parent::setMedia();
          Tools::addCSS(_THEME_CSS_DIR_.'blog.css');
          Tools::addJS(_THEME_JS_DIR_.'blog.js');
  }

  public function displayContent()
  {
           parent::displayContent();
           self::$smarty->display(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'blog.tpl');
  }
}
?>
```

---

**blog.php** (located at root directory)

```
<?php
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/header.php');

ControllerFactory::getController('BlogController')->run();

include(dirname(__FILE__).'/footer.php');
?>
```

---

**blog.tpl** (located at theme directory)

```
{capture name=path}{l s='Blog'}{/capture}

<h1>{l s='Blog posts'}</h1>
```

---

My question is, how can I add some mysql queries (select, show) into the pages and display my blog posts (using a while loop maybe?) in the blog page?

**Edit:**

I tried adding sql queries to `blog.php`, but the results are not displayed on the template page.

I get an error when blog.php saying

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/ystaajux/public_html/blog.php on line 15
Array
Warning: require_once(/home/ystaajux/public_html/controllers/BlogController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ystaajux/public_html/classes/ControllerFactory.php on line 43
```

when I tried running the following in blog.php

```
$results = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS('
            SELECT `id_order`
            FROM `ps_orders`');

$orders = array();

foreach($results as $result) {
    $orders[] = $result['id_order'];
}

echo $orders;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are with Prestashop 1.6, I think you must use initContent() instead of displayContent() in your BlogController.php like :

```
public function initContent()
{
    // you can put your sql queries here and uses smarty to send variables to your view blog.tpl
    parent::initContent();
    $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'blog.tpl');
}
```

But it would be better to use the creation of modules to do what you want.